# Git to docker export

Tags: docker

I'd like some opinions on this workflow. The intention is to semi-automate and revision control the creation/export of docker containers.

I have some docker directories with a dockerfile etc inside (enough to build a docker image from). At the moment, I've set up a process where this becomes a local git repo, then I set up a bare repo on a remote server. Then I add in an 'update' hook to the remote repo that will take the name of the repo and call a script that proceeds to clone that repo, build docker image, start a container, export container, delete repo. Then I end up with a .tar of my docker container every time I push an update to that repo.

The only issue is that I have to manually copy the hook to each remote repo I set up (considering .git/hooks doesn't get pushed from local).

So I'm looking for some feedback on whether this whole process has any intelligence to it or if I am going about it the completely wrong way.

Comment: I think you might want to look at [captain](https://github.com/harbur/captain).

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called "Continuous Integration".

There are multiple ways to achieve it, but here's how I do it:

- Set up a Jenkins server
- Put all docker files into *one* git repo, as modules if necessary
- Have Jenkins check for changes in the repo every few minutes
- Have Jenkins build the docker images after pulling in the changes

Comment: You can also setup automated builds on Dockerhub